# fill data from sql to grid view

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am trying to fill data in grid view from SQL. I have been given a user access when I click a button and fill data in grid view. But i get an error there is already an open data reader associated with this command which must be closed first.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            If ComboBox2.Text = "-----select-----" Then
                MsgBox("Please Select Region and Site ID", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "failure")
            Else
                Button3.Show()
                Button4.Show()
                Button5.Show()
                connection_open()
                qry = "select * from LOG_ACCESS where ID='" & UCase(Environ$("Username")) & "' "
                cmd1 = New SqlCommand(qry, cnn)
                dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader
                If dr.Read = True Then
                    MsgBox("login successful", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "login")
                    qry1 = "select * from SITE_DETAILS where Region = '" + ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString + "' And Site_ID = '" + ComboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString + "'"
                    adp = New SqlDataAdapter(qry1, cnn)
                    dr.Close()
                    adp.Fill(ds, "SITE_DETAILS")
                    'dr.Close()
                    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
                    DataGridView1.DataMember = ds.Tables(0).ToString
                    DataGridView1.Hide()
                    'Me.Hide()
                    'dr.Close()
                    connection_close()

                Else
                    MsgBox("Please Contact Administrator", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "failure")
                    dr.Close()
                    connection_close()
                End If
            End If
            dr.Close()
            connection_close()
        Catch ex As SqlException
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "SqlError")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In your connection string set MARS="true"

Try this instead of `dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader`

```
dr = comm.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply nagaraj. i have tried as per your advise. but still i am getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the problem isn't what's going on in your open_connection method.

Generally, when I've seen data grids filled, it is in the context of a using statement... (Using sql SQLConnection ...) Have you tried that approach?

This way your connection is only open with the braces of the using scope... and once the block is finished, it will be automatically disposed so you won't need all those .close in your if logic.

Here's a link you might find helpful:
http://www.canofcode.co.uk/software/c-sharp-using-statement/